# Crear array sin método map

Tags: javascript, array, arraylist, javascript-objeto

¿Cómo podría crear un array con los name nada mas pero sin el metodo map, o sea yo crear mi propio map utilizando el metodo push?

- Lista de personas:

```
    let sujetos = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Daniel',
        edad: 18,
        pais: 'Venezuela'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Jose',
        edad: 16,
        pais: 'Uruguay'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Carlos',
        edad: 20,
        pais: 'Colombia'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Sebastian',
        edad: 15,
        pais: 'Ecuador'
    },
    ]
```

Aquí es donde no se como hacer para que solo me estraiga las propiedades name de los objetos, solamente estoy extrayendo todas las propiedas y e intentado todo pero nose no me da la lógica:

```
    let aggObject = (nombres) => {
        let arr = []
        for(i=0; i<nombres.length; i++){
             arr.push(nombres[i])
        }
       return arr
    }
```

- Aquí lo imprimo:

```
    console.log(aggObject(sujetos))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal y como lo tienes, tendrías que cambiar la línea:

```
arr.push(nombres[i])
```

**A**:

```
arr.push(nombres[i].name)
```

Te faltaba acceder a la key `name` donde se encuentra el nombre.

- Si quisieras acceder al id:

```
nombres[i].id
```

- Si quisieras acceder al país:

```
nombres[i].pais
```

Y así sucesivamente.

De esta manera al hacer el console.log te devolverá:

```
(4) ["Daniel", "Jose", "Carlos", "Sebastian"]
```

Por lo que quedaría finalmente:

```
let aggObject = (nombres) => {
    let arr = []
    for(i=0; i<nombres.length; i++){
         arr.push(nombres[i].name)
    }
    return arr
}
```

**Más información**:

- [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array)
- [Trabajando con JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON)

Answer (score 1):

Dada tu lista llamada `sujetos`

```
const arr = []
for(i=0; i<sujetos.length; i++){
     arr.push(sujetos[i].name)
}
```

No tengo muy claro porque no quieres usar map, ya que map crea un nuevo array también.

```
const arr = sujetos.map( (v) => v.name )
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu propio método map: Simplemente recorre el array y ejecuta para cada elemento la función que te pasen, guardando en un nuevo array los resultados de la función. En este caso, sólo necesitas una función que devuelva el cambo nombre de cada elemento:

```js
function miMap(array, funct) {
  const resultado = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    resultado.push(funct(array[i]));
  }
  return resultado;
}



//función para extraer el nombre de un elemento:
function extraeNombre(elemento) {
  return elemento.name;
}

let sujetos = [
  {    id: 1,    name: 'Daniel',    edad: 18,    pais: 'Venezuela'},
  {    id: 2,    name: 'Jose',    edad: 16,    pais: 'Uruguay'},
  {    id: 3,    name: 'Carlos',    edad: 20,    pais: 'Colombia'},
  {    id: 4,    name: 'Sebastian',    edad: 15,    pais: 'Ecuador'}
]

console.log(miMap(sujetos, extraeNombre));
```